# Upjack Markdown to include a train-of-thought type syntax

Tags: feature-request, markdown, hyperlinks

I notice that when I read answers I usually end up following some long train of thought that the author intended to illustrate. Or whenever I answer a question I often want to say, "first read this link, then move on to this article which it references for more in-depth information."

I was wondering whether this kind of navigational pattern should be integrated into Markdown. So that apart from placing a link I can also define a Train-Of-Thought.

Something like this:

```
{TOT(link1[this is an overview],link2[this is an in-depth review of the reasons],
 link3[this is new technology references],link4[this is a bashing blog post])}
```

And the resulting answer would look something like this:

Train-of-Thought:

- this is an overview - link
- in-depth review of the reasons - link
- new technology reference - link
- bashing post - link

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you are asking for here. What keeps you from posting your train of thought with a normal Markup list? Why would you complicate the syntax for this feature?

Comment: well one possible reason would be to group all the links together in a sort of a flow. The idea being that one would lead to another, I understand that the format I presented is not a big improvement, I'm trying to take a step in that direction

Answer (score 12):

I strongly disagree with this suggestion.

One of the most important features of Markup is it's relative simplicity (when compare to other Wiki-like or almost-text formats).

Adding special-case syntax for very limited use cases (and with a very specific semantic meaning) will not improve this.

While I can see the benefit of occasionally posting a train of thought on a thorough answer, I see no reason to add an additional syntax construct for this, when a simple list with links works just fine.